# Use a different variable for each domain in a Greasemonkey script

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have a Greasemonkey script that saves a list of numeric IDs as a delimited string using `GM_setValue()`. The script uses this list to filter out items on a bulletin board.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to make this script work for multiple domains, so each domain has its own list of IDs. As it stands now, if I filter out ID "12345" on one site, it will also be filtered on every other site.

I realize I could append the domain to each ID and search for a combination of ID + domain, but I'd prefer to save space unless it's my only choice. Ideally I'd have a separate variable for each domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `location.hostname` to get the domain and then generate a key for use with `GM_setValue` and `GM_getValue`.  After that, the rest of your code is the same.

For example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Store and retrieve a comman var that's unique to each domain
// @include  http://DOMAIN_1.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @include  http://DOMAIN_2.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @include  http://DOMAIN_3.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant    GM_getValue
// @grant    GM_setValue
// ==/UserScript==
var storageKey  = "IDs_" + location.hostname;
var idList      = GM_getValue (storageKey, "");

console.log ("This site's list was: ", idList);

idList         += ",7";

GM_setValue (storageKey, idList);
```

This keeps a separate `idList` for each domain you visit (That matches the @include, @match, and @exclude directives).